# Using a class/struct/union over multiple cpp files C++

Tags: c++, class, header, struct, include

I am trying to create a class in C++ and be able to access elements of that class in more than one C++ file. I have tried over 7 possible senarios to resolve the error but have been unsuccessful. I have looked into class forward declaration which doesen't seem to be the answer (I could be wrong).

```
//resources.h
class Jam{
public:
int age;
}jam;

//functions.cpp
#include "resources.h"
void printme(){
std::cout << jam.age;
}

//main.cpp
#include "resources.h"
int main(){
printme();
std::cout << jam.age;
}
```

`Error  1   error LNK2005: "class Jam jam" (?jam@@3VJam@@A) already defined in stdafx.obj`

`Error  2   error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found`

I understand the error is a multiple definiton because I am including `resources.h` in both CPP files. How can I fix this? I have tried declaring the `class Jam` in a CPP file and then declaring `extern class Jam jam;` for each CPP file that needed to access the class. I have also tried declaring pointers to the class, but I have been unsuccessful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `jam` is defined in the H file, and included in multiple CPP classes, which is a problem.

Variables shouldn't be declared in H files, in order to avoid precisely that. Leave the class definition in the H file, but define the variable in **one** of the CPP files (and if you need to access it globally - define it as `extern` in all the rest).

For example:

```
//resources.h
class Jam{
public:
int age;
};
extern Jam jam; // all the files that include this header will know about it

//functions.cpp
#include "resources.h"
Jam jam; // the linker will link all the references to jam to this one
void printme(){
std::cout << jam.age;
}

//main.cpp
#include "resources.h"
int main(){
printme();
std::cout << jam.age;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring the structure `Jam` *and* creating a variable called `jam` of this type. The linker is complaining that you've got two (or more) things called `jam`, because your header causes each `.cpp` file to declare one of its own.

To fix this, change your header declaration to:

```
class Jam{
public:
int age;
};

extern Jam jam;
```

And then place the following line in *one* of your `.cpp` sources:

```
Jam jam;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate your definition from your declaration.  Use:

```
//resources.h
class Jam{
public:
int age;
};
// Declare but don't define jam
extern Jam jam;

//resources.cpp
// Define jam here; linker will link references to this definition:
Jam jam;
```

Answer (score 1):

As a first step you should separate the definition of the class and declaration of an instance. Then use extern in resources.h and declare the instance in a CPP.

Like this:

```
//resources.h
class Jam{
public:
    int age;
};

extern Jam jam;

//functions.cpp
#include "resources.h"
void printme(){
    std::cout << jam.age;
}

//main.cpp
#include "resources.h"
Jam jam;

int main(){
    printme();
    std::cout << jam.age;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the pragma once directive, or some defines to make sure a header doesn't get included more than once in your code.

Example using pragma directive (example.h):

```
#pragma once
// Everything below the pragma once directive will only be parsed once
class Jam { ... } jam;
```

Example using defines (example.h):

```
#ifndef _EXAMPLE_H
#define _EXAMPLE_H
// This define makes sure this code only gets parsed once
class Jam { ... } jam;
#endif
```